Overriding Scorpio Quarkus application properties from Kubernetes pod ENV - Java Kafka Quarkus Version
Scoprio Broker claims that all of the variables in application.properties of aaio can be overridden from container ENV by replacing . to _ and making all uppercase. So, in application properties here, https://github.com/ScorpioBroker/ScorpioBroker/blob/development-quarkus/AllInOneRunner/src/main/resources/application.properties, I see a variable jdbcurl. Can i override that in Docker ENV using JDBCURL=<postgres_url> ? I tried, but doesn't seem to work like descirbed in docs. What am I missing? Am i wrong or the docs are?
Should I build the Scorpio from source with updated application.properties? Are Scorpio Docs legit?
I also tried this https://github.com/ScorpioBroker/ScorpioBroker/blob/development-quarkus/docs/en/source/buildScorpio.rst, passing --quarkus.datasource.url, --writer.datasource.url and --reader.datasource.url in args of pod spec. No luck.
My pod spec:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: connectivity-test
  labels:
    role: connectivity-test
spec:
  containers:
  - name: scorpio
    image: scorpiobroker/all-in-one-runner:java-kafka-latest
    args: ["--writer.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/ngb?ApplicationName=aio-runner&sslmode=require --reader.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/ngb?ApplicationName=aio-runner&sslmode=require --quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://<ip>:5432/ngb"]

None of the above ENV works. The Pod container just takes the default vlaue for postgres that is jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/ngb
You can see that I dont need just to give custom postgres URL, I also want to add sslmode=require. so DBHOST and DBPASS ENV doesnt help me.
